# Attribute cannot be scraped, even though it's on the page

Tags: excel, web-scraping, excel-2010, spreadsheet, vba

I am trying to get some data into my Excel sheet. For example, when you put in this link into `A2`:

```
http://www.amazon.com/Faulkner-WL-2015A-6-Speed-Folding-Pedal/dp/B00S73PQ2E/ref=sr_1_26?s=outdoor-recreation&ie=UTF8&qid=1446493717&sr=1-26&keywords=folding+bike
```

The following error occurs:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
 Public Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)

Sub ScrapeAmz()

    Dim Ie As New InternetExplorer
    Dim WebURL
    Dim Docx As HTMLDocument
    Dim productDesc
    Dim productTitle
    Dim price
    Dim imagePath
    Dim RcdNum
    Dim imgObj
    Dim featureBullets
    Dim reviews

    Ie.Visible = False

    For RcdNum = 2 To ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

        WebURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A" & RcdNum)
        Ie.Navigate2 WebURL
        Do Until Ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
            DoEvents
        Loop
        Set Docx = Ie.document
        productTitle = Docx.getElementById("productTitle").innerText

'####### Image
        'Set imgObj = Docx.getElementsByTagName("img")
        'imagePath = imgObj(1).getAttribute("src")
        Dim el4 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

        On Error Resume Next
        Set el4 = Docx.getElementById("landingImage").getAttribute("src")
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not el4 Is Nothing Then
            imagePath = ""
        Else
            imagePath = Docx.getElementById("landingImage").getAttribute("src")
        End If

'print to workbook
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("B" & RcdNum) = productTitle
'ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C" & RcdNum) = productDesc
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("E" & RcdNum) = imagePath
        Sleep (5000)
    Next

End Sub
```

I am getting the error at the following line:

```
    Else
        imagePath = Docx.getElementById("landingImage").getAttribute("src") ' here I get the error
    End If
```

The purpose of this section is that, if no attribute is available the program should output an empty string.

```
            Dim el4 As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

            On Error Resume Next
            Set el4 = Docx.getElementById("landingImage").getAttribute("src")
            On Error GoTo 0
            If Not el4 Is Nothing Then
                imagePath = ""
            Else
                imagePath = Docx.getElementById("landingImage").getAttribute("src")
            End If
```

Any suggestions, what I am doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

Yes, I debugged my code. See the following picture for an overview:

[image]

My problem is that it looks weird to me that the `imagePath` var is `empty` or even goes into this `else-clause`.

Comment: Did you debug this? Like, see variable values to check if there are no null references? And e.g. use the immediate window to determine which specific operation of the many on the line gives the error?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Please do not downvote so fast. I debugged my code and attached the output as an image above. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this:

```
    If Not el4 Is Nothing Then
        imagePath = ""
    Else
        imagePath = Docx.getElementById("landingImage").getAttribute("src")
    End If
```

with this:

```
    If el4 Is Nothing Then
        imagePath = ""
    Else
        imagePath = Docx.getElementById("landingImage").getAttribute("src")
    End If
```